# Rename uploaded file in PHP using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have this code and would like to rename the uploaded image's name!

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" capture>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php 
    $target_path = "upload/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

What can i do?

Comment: From the docs... http://php.net/manual/de/function.rename.php

Comment: just adjust the `$target_path` ...

Comment: Wow, I was looking for an upload script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)` you can specify the name of the file at the destination.

```
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_filename = 'filename.xyz'
$target_path = $target_path . $target_filename); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  $target_filename). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

cf. [move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)